# Tkinter: PanedWindow not stretching within Frames

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create two "pages" in the main window with Frames and PanedWindows. The "Main" class uses a PanedWindow which is inherited by the two pages. They are then being initialized as Frames which consist of either PanedWindow(s) or Frame(s). The Problem is that **they don't stretch**. Neither of them have a sash despite that it has been added (*sashwidth=50*).

I have checked in stackoverflow, but didn't found anything relevant. Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Program")

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        container = tk.PanedWindow(self, bg='bisque',orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, relief='groove', borderwidth=2, sashwidth=3)
        container.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.frames = {}        

        main_page = MainPage(container, self)
        self.frames[0] = main_page
        main_page.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        plotting_page = PlottingPage(container, self)
        self.frames[1] = plotting_page
        plotting_page.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
    
class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # Paned Windows
        top_pane = tk.PanedWindow(self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, relief='groove', borderwidth=2, sashwidth=3)
        top_pane.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="nsew", columnspan=4)
        top_pane.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        top_pane.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        top_pane.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        top_pane.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        bottom_pane = tk.PanedWindow(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL, relief='groove', borderwidth=2, sashwidth=50)
        bottom_pane.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="nsew", columnspan=2)
        bottom_pane.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        bottom_pane.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        bottom_pane.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        bottom_pane.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        # Frames      
        top_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text="Top frame")
        bottom_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text="Bottom frame")

        # Layout of frames
        top_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        bottom_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="ew")

        top_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        top_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        top_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        top_frame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        top_pane.add(top_frame, stretch="always")

        bottom_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        bottom_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        bottom_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        bottom_frame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        bottom_pane.add(bottom_frame, stretch="always")

    
        top = tk.Label(top_frame, text="top pane")
        top.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="nsew")

        bottom = tk.Label(bottom_frame, text="bottom pane")
        bottom.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="nsew")

        

class PlottingPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # Paned Windows
        right_pane = tk.PanedWindow(self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, relief='groove', borderwidth=2, sashwidth=3)
        right_pane.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky="nsew", columnspan=4)
        right_pane.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        right_pane.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        right_pane.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        right_pane.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        # Frames      
        right_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text="Right frame")

        # Layout of frames
        right_frame.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nsew")

        right_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        right_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        right_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        right_frame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        right_pane.add(right_frame, stretch="always")

        # Widgets
        right = tk.Label(right_frame, text="right pane")
        right.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="nsew")

def main():
    app = Main()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Really? Nobody knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, that i hadn't configured all columns & rows. You should use columnconfigure, rowconfigure for EVERY row & column inside that "span".